# To find all the primitive roots $\bmod 50$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

To find all the the primitive roots of the following:

- $\bmod 25$
- $\bmod 125$
- $\bmod 50$

---

Note that $2$ is a primitive root $\mod 5$ and $25 = 5^2, 125 = 5^3$. Then using the fact that the primitive roots are $2^j$, where $j$ is relatively prime to $\phi(25) = 20$ for $25$ and $\phi(125) = 100$ for $125$ we can list all the primitive roots.

---

But $50 = 2\times 5^2$. How to find all the primitive roots $\bmod 50$?

Any hints will be of great help.

The problem was given as a homework problem. I could to the first 2 parts only the 3rd part I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a theorem that if $g^{\varphi(n)/k}\ne 1\pmod n$ for each prime divisor $k\mid \varphi (n)$, then $g$ is primitive $\pmod n$.

You can check that $\varphi (50)=20$;  and that $3^{10},3^4\ne1\pmod{50}$.

Thus $3$ is primitive $\pmod{50}$.

Now use $\varphi $.

Comment: Sorry...but what do you mean by saying that "Now use $\varphi$"?

Comment: Since $\varphi (20)=8$, you can get $7$ more,  by raising $3$ to powers relatively prime to $20$.

Comment: Ok got it thanks.

Comment: Can you give a reference to the theorem?

Comment: Yes, I.M. Vinogradov, "Elements of Number Theory", Dover(2015), p.108